# How to apply telerik transition to a border that has been created in XAML code

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik

I have the following XAML in my program

```
 <Border x:Name="topCornerBorder" CornerRadius="10" Height="auto" Width="auto" Background="White">
        <Grid x:Name="topCorner" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="190*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="270*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Canvas x:Name="textBlockCanvas1">
        </Canvas>
     </StackPanel>

        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
            <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Width="300" Canvas.Top="15" Canvas.Left="100" Visibility="Collapsed" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" RowBackground="Aqua" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" CanUserResizeColumns="false" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  BorderThickness="3"
                         CanUserReorderColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                    <!--Column stuff here not important for this question..-->

                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </Canvas>    
    </Grid>
```

and i tried to set the transition by doing the following:

```
  <telerik:RadTransitionControl Name="radTransitionControl" Duration="00:00:01" Content="{Binding topCornerBorder}" >
        <telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition >
            <telerik:SlideAndZoomTransition/>
        </telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>
    </telerik:RadTransitionControl>
```

But nothing is happening. I also tried the following in the C# code behind:

```
radTransitionControl.Content = this.topCornerBorder;
```

But this results in an error "Value does not fall within expected range".

What do i have to do to successfully set the transition content property to the border that surrounds the rest of my UI elements?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Transition Control incorrectly.

The control is simply a content control which triggers an animation when the content changes.

Typically, you would break visuals up into individual User Controls, and set the content of the Transition Control at the appropriate time.

---

In the simplest example, you might have two UserControls (View1.xaml and View2.xaml). From code you would set

```
radTransitionControl.Content = new View1();
```

Then you would set

```
radTransitionControl.Content = new View2();
```

In the second set operation, you would expect to see the transition occur.

---

Note that none of the transitions will happen if the setters are called before the Transition Control has been loaded.

Also note that this `Content="{Binding topCornerBorder}` doesnt work because `topCornerBorder` is an element, and not a property.

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=topCornerBorder}
```

Is syntactically correct but will probably result in an `exception` because topCornerBorder is already part of the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

Well i was able to apply the transition to the border (and everything else inside of it) by simply doing:

```
radTransitionControl.PrepareAnimation();
```

I don't know if that's the correct way to do it but it's working so far.